# Subtract is working fine in this way but not the addition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have just started learning angularjs. I was trying to perform arithmetic operations. Subtract is working fine but while adding values of both the input field gets concat. What I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Number 1 : <input type="text" ng-model="num1" placeholder="Enter name here"></p><br><br>
<p>Number 2 : <input type="text" ng-model="num2" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
<h1>Number 1: {{num1}</h1><br>
<h1>Number 2: {{num2}}</h1><br>

<h1>Sum {{num1 + num2}}</h1>
<h1>Subtract {{num1 - num2}}</h1>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with AngularJS, just the JS: `"1" - "2" === -1`, `"1" + "2" === "12"`. If you want to deal consistently with numbers, parse the strings.

Comment: Or use inputs of type number, and not of type text. text is for text. number is for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="number">`:

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">
<p>Number 1 : <input type="number" ng-model="num1" placeholder="Enter number here"></p>
<p>Number 2 : <input type="number" ng-model="num2" placeholder="Enter number here"></p>
Number 1: {{num1}}<br>
Number 2: {{num2}}<br>

<div>Sum {{num1 + num2}}</div>
<div>Subtract {{num1 - num2}}</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `'+'` used to concat two strings instead of the addition operator.
for adding numbers as you have taken num1 and num2,  you can take advantage of `'-'`operator.

```
<div>Sum: {{num1 - (-num2)}}</div>
```